# java.io.File - suitable for simple hierarchy of virtual and non-virtual files?

Tags: java, file, synchronization

I am programming a server/client program, which compares to folders (folder A and folder B, and their subfolders). I want to be able to compare folders within my computer as well as to remote folders.

Therefore i will implement a communication protocol, which sends the name of the folders and their subfolders so that I can reconstruct the hierarchy.

Would it be performant to use java's *File* class for the remote folders? Or should I continue writing my own little File and Folder Classes?

Thank you!

Comment: It would consider using VFS fir remote folders

Comment: I guess what I'm currently doing is building a very very simple virtual filesystem. But is that really necessary? In the end, what my application does is comparing strings of File/Folder names and then building the diff of two folders.

Comment: do you mean like `rsync` does?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I just want to know the diff and of course practice programming.